# Make a new pandas.dataframe column as filtered other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.Dataframe object in the following format:

```
Symb     Bid     Ask
ESU6     207000  207025
YMU6     12793   12797
ESU6     207025  207050
YMU6     12795   12797
```

But I want to re-configure the object to look like the following format:

```
Bid.ESU6     Ask.ESU6     Bid.YMU6     Ask.YMU6
207000       207025       
                          12793        12797
207025       207050       
                          12795        12797
```

Is there an easy way to re-configure the data without a for-loop that goes through each element?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(columns='Symb', values=['Bid','Ask'], index=df.index)
df1.sort_index(axis=1, level=1, inplace=True)
df1.columns = ['.'.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
print (df1)
  Bid.ESU6 Ask.ESU6 Bid.YMU6 Ask.YMU6
0   207000   207025                  
1                      12793    12797
2   207025   207050                  
3                      12795    12797
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much! Before you answered, I figured out a similar way to get it, which is to cycle through all the symbols and cycle through all the columns, sort of similar to the following: 

     for symb in symbols:
          for col in df.columns:
              df[col + '.' + symb] = df[col][(df['Symb'] == symb)] 
     for col in df.columns:
          del df[col]

but, I believe your code is more efficient. Thank you!